# Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x00442FF8)

Tags: c++

Algorithm checks if both variables "a" and "x" are prime numbers.If yes, it simply announce that these are prime.Need 50 of them, when it comes to 6th position program shows an error:

> Exception thrown at 0x00D02509 in ConsoleApplication3.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x002D2F5C). Unhandled exception at 0x00D02509 in ConsoleApplication3.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x002D2F5C).

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int CheckIfPrime(long int n)
{
    if (n<2) return 0;
    for (int i = 2; i*i <= n; i++)
        if (n%i == 0) return 0;
    return 1;
}

int pow(int ap, int nt)
{
    if (nt == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return ap *= pow(ap, --nt);
}

void CountA(int *aValue, int x)
{
    *aValue = (pow(2, x) - 1);
}

int main()
{
    int x = 1;
    int a = 0;
    int *aPointer = &a;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 50;)
    {
        x++;
        if (CheckIfPrime(x))
        {
            CountA(aPointer, x);
            if (CheckIfPrime(a))
            {
                cout << i << ". X = " << x << " a = " << a  << " are prime " << endl;
                    i++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "";
        }
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Took me a moment to realize:  By "stack overflow" you mean this forum, not that malfunction.  Your code would have a stack overflow if you passed a negative `x` into `CountA` but you don't.  Aside from that, you code is just horribly wrong and no change less than redesign from scratch could make it work above tiny values of `x`

Comment: Well the main point of this code is to check if x variable is prime: if true, then it counts a = 2^x -1. After that algorithm checks if 'a' is prime.

Comment: Exception thrown at 0x00D02509 in ConsoleApplication3.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x002D2F5C).


Unhandled exception at 0x00D02509 in ConsoleApplication3.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x002D2F5C).

That's the output

Comment: You use `int` to hold everything computed within `CountA` so any `x` above 31 will produce garbage.  (31 is also undefined overflow, but could easily work by accident).

Comment: OK, I missed the real stack overflow, since I didn't look past the generally wrong code.  Because the code is generally wrong, `x` is incremented repeatedly without `i` being incremented, until `x` is large enough to trigger the stack overflow.

Comment: The stack overflow seems illogical in this one, someone tell me what 0x00000001, 0x00442FF8 means in english? [EDIT:] actually no i dont think itll help... it just seems to be a random number, its not a description [edit] youve got some bugs, i bet your text isnt outputting, but why the SO? no idea. Im back, in my one my problem was i was sending too big a paramtre in!!! (also causes stack over flow.) stuff knows whats wrong with yours. :) but if you want to try make the parametre a reference instead of the actual data type.

Comment: Looks like a good time for you to learn using a debugger. It should catch the exception and show you where it comes from. Then examine  the stack to understand what led the program to SO.

Answer (score 1):

You have stack overflow in function:

```
int pow(int ap, int nt)
{
  if (nt == 0)
    return 1;
  else
    return ap *= pow(ap, --nt);
}
```

for very large nt it will enter too deeply in recursion causing SO

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compute exact integer 2 to the power `x` for some rather large values of `x`.  No ordinary data type can hold that value.  But if you had some data type holding that value, then testing whether the result minus one is prime by that simplistic method would take more time than the life of the universe.

You are attacking a very hard and very well studied problem, and using nothing but naive ignorance as a tool.

https://primes.utm.edu/mersenne/